# I have a problem with animation sheet on godot 3.1

Tags: godot

I'm trying to create a sprite's animation using an animation sheet on Godot 3.1 but when I select the number of `Hframes` and `Vframes`, it doesn't correctly select the sprite texture; it takes a little bit of another frame.

Is there a way to solve that? a way to select the size of the frame selection or something?

Answer (score 1):

> it takes a little bit of another frame

This is more than likely due to your predefined grid step, for example, if your `sprite atlas` or `sprite sheet` says that each cell is 16x16 then you must set it to that instead of something like 32x32.

Once you do this the grid will properly align to each sprite. Note that the example below I'm using a `Sprite Atlas`

[image]